# How can I add an external image to a word document using PHPWord?

Tags: php, docx, phpword

I can create word document with imbedded image:

```
// Remote image
$source = 'http://php.net/images/logos/php-med-trans-light.gif';
$section->addText("Remote image from: {$source}");
$section->addImage($source);
```

In this case image will be downloaded using [`file_get_contents()`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Element/Image.php#L418) (without timeout!) and included into docx archive.

But I dont need to download image. How can I insert image with relation to external resource?

Comment: Are you able to achieve this in word? When I add an image in word from a URL, it actually downloads the image and stores it in the document. If word cannot do it PHPWord certainly cannot.

Comment: @troosan, Its possible to create docx with links to images manually using libreoffice console converter from HTML to docx.